# Derangement Numbers within a sum

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

I need help with a question, I need to show that the derangement numbers $D_n$ satisfy $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} D_n \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!} =  \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}$$

I also need to prove that the expected number of fixed points of a permutation is $1$. I am so lost any help is appreciated.

Comment: The second part is much easier than the first part (unless you already know the formula for $D_n.$ It’s a simple application of linearity of expectations.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be the value of the infinite sum on the LHS. Using the recurrence $ D_{n+2}= (n+1)(D_{n+1}+D_n)$ (which you can prove), show that $f$ satisfies a second order differential equation, and solve it.

Comment: @redneckmathematician If you give the integral for the expected number of points, one may try getting it.

Answer (score 1):

For derangements, we get the combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots)$$

which yields the EGF

$$F(z) =
\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$

which is

$$\exp\left(-z + \log\frac{1}{1-z} \right)
= \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}.$$

For the expected number of fixed points we use

$$\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots)$$

with EGF

$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left(uz +
\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$

which is

$$\exp\left(uz  - z + \log\frac{1}{1-z} \right)
= \frac{\exp(uz)\exp(-z)}{1-z}.$$

We get for the expectation of the number of fixed points

$$[z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = [z^n] \left. z\frac{\exp(uz)\exp(-z)}{1-z} \right|_{u=1}
= [z^n] \frac{z}{1-z} = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral representation of the derangements $D_n$ is
$$D_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} (t-1)^n e^{-t} dt.$$ Then
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}(t-1)^n e^{-t} dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{x(t-1)} e^{-t} dt= e^{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1-x)t} dt= \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}.$$